# Usage of 'stilsicher' in context of language proficiency?

Tags: usage

Apparently 'stilsicher' translates as 'stylish' but I frequently see it used to describe one's proficiency in a language -e.g. 'Ihre Deutschkenntnisse sind stilsicher'. 
It just appears at first an odd word to use here - does it have any other added, or deeper, meaning other than 'stylish', and how, where, else is this word used?

Comment: It can mean *stylish* but that's a derived meaning. The actual meaning is you are *confident in stilistic challenges*. Meaning you *just know* which thing goes with another. It's the holy grail of profiency.

Comment: Yes. But be aware, exams do not always tell the truth.

Comment: This was in a job advertisement :)

Comment: No this isn't the same as "near native level", simply because of the fact, that many (most??) native speakers arent "stilsicher"

Comment: I was up to write this but how far can one get?

Comment: @hinterbu: In that case, forget it, they want a poet. Usually for writing tedious things as rejections to job application letters.

Comment: Are u ok Janka? You sound angry at life somehow'. Feeling/being 'up to write' something, as you said you were, should help the poets along :)

Comment: Only trying to be an embittered poet from time to time.

Comment: "Stilsicher" refers to proficiency better than that of the "average" native. I.e. "university" level, rather than secondary or trade school graduate.

Comment: @Janka One doesn't ever 'try' to be an embittered poet. I don't think you are as well-placed as you believe yourself to be to be commenting with any authority on stilsicher-ness ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Stilsicher" means you are able to decide to which level of the language an expression, a word usage, a grammatical construction or  a saying belongs, and that you use this properly in its right contexts. Language levels could be: high German, colloquial, slang, occupational jargon, poetic, dialect, children's language and many more.
If you are "stilsicher" enough you can also go outside of these boundaries, and use expressions that are out of place, but meant tounge-in-cheek, as a joke or ironically.

I'd say you don't usually comment on ones language skills with the expression "stilsicher". This is more of what could be requiered, to be able to manage some situations. It doesn't come naturally, only because you're a native speaker. It takes a lot of reading, writing and talking to aquire this.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate "Stilsicher" as "style *sure*" or "sure of style," rather than "stylish."

"Sure of style" refers to a very high level of language proficiency, that even some native speakers can't attain. This is, you are not only "sure" or "sicher" regarding vocabulary, but also of style and nuances of the language. That is to say that you can make very subtle points in the language.

"Stylish" only means that you can "go with the crowd." Whereas "style sure" or Stilsicher suggests that you can rise above it.